# Determining an algorithm to calculate individual item prices for "deal" listings

Tags: algorithm

Here are a couple of example scenarios about what I'm trying to figure out:

Let's say a grocery store item is listed as `4 for 5.00`. How do we go about figuring the unit price for each item, according to the deal that is listed?

A simple solution would be to divide the total price by the quantity listed, and in this case, you would get `1.25`.

However, in a situation that is a bit more complicated, such as `3 for 5.00`, dividing the price by the quantity gives roughly `1.6666666666666667`, which would round to `1.67`.

If we round all three items to `1.67`, the total price is not `5.00`, but in fact `5.01`. The individual prices would need to be calculated as `1.67`, `1.67`, and `1.66` in order to add up correctly.

The same goes for something like `3 for 4.00`. The mathematical unit price would be `1.3333333333333333`, rounding to `1.33`. However, we need to adjust one of them again because the actual price without adjustments would be `3.99`. The individual prices would need to be `1.34`, `1.33`, and `1.33` to add up correctly.

Is there an efficient way to determine how to split up a price deal like this and how to determine adjusted amounts so that the individual prices add up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to divide an integer number (e.g. of pence) up into as equal portions as possible one way is to mimic dividing up that portion of a line by making marks in it, so portion i of n (counting from 0) when the total is T is of length floor((T * (i + 1)) / n) - floor((T * i) / n).

Whether it makes sense to say the the individual prices of 3 items are 1.67, 1.67, and 1.66 is another matter. How do you decide which item is the cheap one?

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that response. In regards to deciding which is the cheap one, that comes from cashiering at a grocery store. I just noticed that's how our POS system does it and I think the cheapest item is always added last. Or, in the case of something like 3/4.00, the most expensive (1.34) is added first.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about basic math here, I'd say efficiency depends more on your implementation than the algorithm. When you say "efficient", do you mean you don't want to add up all prices to check the remainder? That can be done:

The premise is, you're selling x items for a price of y, where x is obviously integer and y is obviously a float rounded to 2 decimals.

First, you need to calculate the remainder: `R = (y*100)%x`.
x-R of the items will cost `(y * 100 : x) /100` (where ":" means integer division and "/" means float division)
and R of the items will cost `(y * 100 : x) / 100 + 0.01`

That algorithm is theoretically speaking efficient since it has a complexity of O(1). But I think I remember that in hardware not much is more efficient than adding floats (Don't take my word for it, I didn't pay that much attention to my hardware lectures), so maybe the crude approach is still better.